# Mysql join table result as one row

Tags: mysql, join, group-concat

I have two tables

**prj**

```
id | ptitle
1  | prj111
2  | prj222
```

**prjflow**

```
id | pid | paction | pactiontxt
 1 |  1  |    1    |     man1
 2 |  1  |    1    |     man2
 3 |  1  |    2    |     woman1
 4 |  1  |    1    |     man3
```

i want this output:

**output**

```
ptitle | men       | women
prj111 | man1,men3 | woman1
```

i write this query:

```
SELECT prj.ptitle
     , GROUP_CONCAT(pflow1.pactiontxt) men
     , GROUP_CONCAT(pflow2.pactiontxt) women 
  FROM prj 
  JOIN prjflow pflow1 
    ON prj.id = pflow1.pid 
   AND pflow1.paction = 1
  JOIN prjflow pflow2 
    ON prj.id = pflow2.pid 
   AND pflow2.paction = 2;
```

but output is:

```
ptitle | men       | women
prj111 | man1,men3 | woman1,woman1
```

My Query when the number of rows of men and women have been equal, working properly
but 
i want that works at any case.

thanks a lot 
and excuse me for poor english writing

Comment: But why, oh why? :-(

Comment: And why is man2 missing from the result set?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT prj.ptitle,
       GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN prjflow.paction = 1 THEN prjflow.pactiontext END ORDER BY prjflow.id) as men,
       GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN prjflow.paction = 2 THEN prjflow.pactiontext END ORDER BY prjflow.id) as women
FROM prj JOIN
     prjflow 
     ON prj.id = prjflow.pid
GROUP BY prj.ptitle;
```

This will also fix two potential problems with your query.  The first is performance.  If some of the titles have large numbers of men and women, then the query has to process a cartesian product.  The second is semantic.  If some titles have men but not women or women without men, then the two joins will filter them out.

[Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fd22f/2) is a SQL Fiddle demonstrating it.

Do note that the suggested output seems inconsistent with the input data.  This produces the output:

```
ptitle | men            | women
prj111 | man1,man2,men3 | woman1
```

I see no reasonable way to exclude `man2` from the list, so I assume that is a typo.

Comment: It was me who downvoted. I didn't intend the comment to be unhelpful. I left the comment because I didn't want to be an anonymous downvoter and wanted to point out the error. But you're right, the problem is solved by this query. I was wrong (for the first time EVER! ;-)) Comment removed, answer upvoted.

Answer (score 0):

The 'quick fix' would be to use `distinct` in the `group_concat` aggregation:

```
SELECT 
  prj.ptitle, 
  group_concat(distinct pflow1.pactiontxt) AS men, 
  group_concat(distinct pflow2.pactiontxt) AS women 
FROM prj 
JOIN prjflow AS pflow1 ON (prj.id = pflow1.pid AND pflow1.paction = 1) 
JOIN prjflow AS pflow2 ON (prj.id = pflow2.pid AND pflow2.paction = 2)
GROUP BY
  prj.ptitle -- Officially you'll need this as well, although MySQL is quite forgiving.
```

But the query still uses two joins, and will even fail if there a no men or no women for a particular project.

So to solve that, you can write the query with subqueries. This way, you won't need joins `distinct` or `group by`, and the query will work too when an item has no men or no women at all.

```
SELECT 
  prj.ptitle, 
  ( SELECT group_concat(pflow1.pactiontxt) FROM prjflo pflow1 
    WHERE prj.id = pflow1.pid AND pflow1.paction = 1) AS men,
  ( SELECT group_concat(pflow2.pactiontxt) FROM prjflo pflow2 
    WHERE prj.id = pflow2.pid AND pflow2.paction = 2) AS women
FROM prj
```

Comment: There isn't a better way?